# About div positions

Tags: javascript, html, width

My page is split into two columns, like this :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left" style="float:left; width:15%;">
        <span style="width:15%"; id="dog">Hi i'm a dog</span>
    </div>

    <div id="right" style="float:left; width:85%;">
        <p>Hello world</p>  
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the height of the span (dog) is positioned using JS :

```
document.getElementById("dog").style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById("dog").style.top = "20px";
```

And in this case, the left column will be considered empty, and the content of the right column will ignore the 15% and start at the left of the screen, overlapping the span text.
So far, I can solve this by just writing at least one character in the left column without JS.

How else can I "force" the right column to start after the 15% of the left column ?

thanks

Comment: set a `min-height` for the left column

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jN9SV/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left" style="float:left; width:15%; min-height:1px">
        <span style="width:15%"; id="dog">Hi i'm a dog</span>
    </div>

    <div id="right" style="float:left; width:85%;">
        <p>Hello world</p>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using float: right for the second division helps if you are dealing with just two divisions.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left" style="float:left; width:15%;">
    <span style="width:15%"; id="dog">Hi i'm a dog</span>
</div>

<div id="right" style="float:right; width:85%;">
    <p>Hello world</p>  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See below - use a combination of "min-width" and change the right div to "float:right":

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left" style="float:left; width:15%; min-width:15%">
        <span style="width:15%"; id="dog"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="right" style="float:right; width:85%;">
        <p>Hello world</p>  
    </div>
</div>
```